# How to replace text in js?

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming I have the following:

```
var s = "This is a test of the battle system."
```

and I had an array:

```
var array = [
"is <b>a test</b>",
"of the <div style=\"color:red\">battle</div> system"
]
```

Is there some function or way I could make it such that I can process the string s such that the output would be:

```
var p = "This is <b>a test</b> of the <div style=\"color:red\">battle</div> system."
```

Based on the arbitrary elements in the array?

Note that the array elements should be executed in sequence. So looking at the first element in array 1, find the correct place to "replace" in string "s". Then looking at array element 2, find the correct place to "replace" in string "s".

Note that the string could contain numbers, brackets, and other characters like dashes (no <> though)

Comment: I wonder how those errors don't become immediately evident given the wrong syntax highlighting. Even if I don't understand the code I can still tell that something is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: after Colin DeClue's remark I think you want to do something different than I originally thought.

Here is how you can accomplish that

```
//your array
var array = [
    "is <b>a test</b>",
    "of the <div style=\"color:red\">battle</div> system"
];
//create a sample span element, this is to use the built in ability to get texts for tags
var cElem = document.createElement("span");

//create a clean version of the array, without the HTML, map might need to be shimmed for older browsers with a for loop;
var cleanArray = array.map(function(elem){
   cElem.innerHTML =  elem;
   return cElem.textContent;
});
//the string you want to replace on
var s = "This is a test of the battle system."

//for each element in the array, look for elements that are the same as in the clean array, and replace them with the HTML versions
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  var idx;//an index to start from, to avoid infinite loops, see discussion with 6502 for more information
  while((idx = s.indexOf(cleanArray[i],idx)) > -1){
    s = s.replace(cleanArray[i],array[i]);
    idx +=(array[i].length - cleanArray[i].length) +1;//update the index
  }
}
//write result 
document.write(s);
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/opudah/9/edit

---

Original answer, in case this is what you meant after all

Yes. Using [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var s = array.join(" ");
```

[Here is a working example in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vshyz)

Comment: I don't think this is what the poster wants. I think the poster wants to start with `s`, use `array` in processing it in someway to output the last `s`.

Comment: Colin is right, this is not what I am looking for. I am looking to take all the elements in the "array" and apply it to string s to achieve the desired result string.

Comment: @Damascusi See the recent edit, let me know if you find that clear, if you don't let me know how I can clarify

Comment: That `escape` function isn't used at the top, by the way. You can get rid of that. (which is nice. We don't want to parse HTML with regex)

Comment: @ColinDeClue Right you are again, I originally thought to join the array on ")|(" and escape the text, however after seeing the code that produced I thought loops were a friendlier approach

Comment: What happens if the array contains `"<b>Test</b>"` ?

Comment: @6502 If there are several matching elements it'll match the first one in the array. It is also case sensitive. OP did not specify if those things mattered, the code above could be easily modified to allow case insensitivity or different order of execution if OP wishes to though :)

Comment: The problem is that after replacement the element will be found again (`"Test"` is contained in `"<b>Test</b>"`). That loop will run forever (well... until the browser kills it).

Comment: @6502 Oh, that won't be a problem because the elements I'm checking for are all text and don't contain HTML to begin with. If that becomes a specification than a different solution is needed

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying. `"Test"` is text only without html tags... but the replacement `"<b>Test</b>"` CONTAINS that text. This means that if you search for the text after the replacement you will find it again producing `"<b><b>Test</b></b>"` this time. Then once again, producing `"<b><b><b>Test</b></b></b>"` this time... and so on...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27043/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-6502)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I suppose you've an array of `original --> replacement` pairs.</strike>

To extract the text from an HTML a trick that may work for you is actually creating a DOM node and then extract the text content.

Once you have the text you can use the `replace` method with a regular expression.
One annoying thing is that searching for an exact string is not trivial because there is no `escape` predefined function in Javascript:

```
function textOf(html) {
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    n.innerHTML = html;
    return n.textContent;
}

var subs = ["is <b>a test</b>",
            "of the <div style=\"color:red\">battle</div> system"];

var s = "This is a test of the battle system"

for (var i=0; i<subs.length; i++) {
    var target = textOf(subs[i]);
    var replacement = subs[i];
    var re = new RegExp(target.replace(/[\\[\]{}()+*$^|]/g, "\\$&"), "g");
    s = s.replace(re, replacement);
}

alert(s);
```